# mobilefirst 8 Adapter xml file schema validation encountered errors

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using MFP 8.0 and trying to build an adapter. Following is the code of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mfp:adapter name="TestAdapter"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:mfp="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
             xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>TestAdapter</displayName>
    <description>TestAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>10.80.111.52</domain>
            <port>8083</port>
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="testProc" scope="restrictedResource"></procedure>

    <JAXRSApplicationClass>com.example.UserLoginValidationApplication</JAXRSApplicationClass>
    <securityCheckDefinition name="UserValidationSecurityCheck" class="com.example.UserLoginValidationResource"></securityCheckDefinition>



</mfp:adapter>
```

The procedure is defined in the js file. When I am building the adapter with `mfpdev adapter build` command I am getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2016070421:build (default-build) on project TestAdapter: Adapter xml file schema validation encountered errors: [cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
 '{procedure, property, securityCheckDefinition}' is expected.] -> [Help 1]
```

I am using mfpdev version **8.0.0-2016091519**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, as well as stated in the error itself, you cannot have the `<JAXRSApplicationClass>` element in the server.xml.

Remove said element and the adapter will be built successfully.

See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/creating-a-security-check/#defining-a-security-check